# How to print out Node Values from BinaryTree with continuing number?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to travers a Binary Tree and print out the **Node Values** with a **matching number** in front of each Node. For better understanding:
I'm printing out **following lines** while Calling my Method:

1. 11 , 2. 33 , 3. 10 , 4. 14 , 5. 27 , 3. 31 , 4. 32

Where as **my Goal** with the Method ist, to **print out the exact same order** of the Nodes **but** with **having an increasing Number infront of it**, which should indicate the order. **Like so:**

1. 11
2. 33
3. 10
4. 14
5. 27
6. 31
7. 32

Till know my Method looks like this:

```
public int mNr(Node k, int Nr) {
        //If the current Node is null, return 0 (currently not making any use of the return)
        if(k == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            //If the left Side is not null print out the Left Node with Value 
            if(k.left != null) {
                //increment Nr each time priniting
                System.out.println("Nr: " + ++Nr + " " + k.left.number);
            }
            if(k.right != null) {
                //Same as left Side
                System.out.println("Nr: " + ++Nr + " " + k.right.number);
            }
            //Calling the Method and not incrementing the Nr Parameter because 
            //already incrementing it in the print Statements
            return mNr(k.left, Nr) + mNr(k.right, Nr);
        }
    }
```

I'm also **not** quite **sure** how to **use** the **int -return**, even till know I'm not making any use of it.
Any Advice for getting the Correct Output would be helpful.

Comment: I see no difference between what you are actually having compared to what would you want to print out.

Comment: Can you explain again what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: first, please, take a time and think about the order of traversal, without it the whole task is pretty pointless

Comment: I edited the Post, the last two number of my Output don't match the Order after 5. 27, i want to print 6. 31 and not 3. 31

Comment: Most likely `Nr` is getting called in `mNr(k.right, Nr);` with its old value, which is why you're getting that result.

Comment: You can make `Nr` static and the result may fix.

Comment: Any other way then declaring a static field or using an extra variable?

Comment: Can you change the way you traverse or is your return required to be 0(as that's what you would get with this)?

Comment: The return ist not required. The only order i would like to maintain is to first print the current left node then the right node

Comment: You could have `mNr` return `Nr` into a previous `Nr` so you can use it in the statements called higher up the tree.

Comment: can you show it in Code?

Comment: So this does not output the very root. ... Is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each recursive call has its own `Nr` variable, they don't always have the same value. If in the deeper recursion, `Nr` is incremented, this does not affect the caller's version of `Nr`.

As you already seemed to hint to, you can use the return value to communicate back to the caller what the latest value of `Nr` is, so that the caller can update its own `Nr` variable, or use it as the caller pleases.

Here is a correction:

```
public int mNr(Node k, int Nr) {
    if(k == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if(k.left != null) {
            System.out.println("Nr: " + ++Nr + " " + k.left.number);
        }
        if(k.right != null) {
            System.out.println("Nr: " + ++Nr + " " + k.right.number);
        }
        // Use the return value from the left-recursion to feed the right-recursion
        return mNr(k.right, mNr(k.left, Nr));
    }
}
```

Having said that, this traversal has some other issues:

- The root node is not included in the output
- The traversal has a peculiar order: it is a mix of depth and breadth first. It would make more sense to choose a more popular traversal, like a pre-order traversal (first parent, then left subtree, then right subtree)

So this leads to the following alternative code:

```
static public int mNr(Node node, int Nr) {
    if (node == null) {
        return Nr;
    }
    System.out.println("Nr: " + ++Nr + " " + node.number);
    return mNr(node.right, mNr(node.left, Nr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns are used to make the result of a method available for further evaluation within the program.
In this case, the method calling `mNr` could used the return of 0 to know that the node is empty and therefore produce a more adequate output for this situation.